# Is it possible to make event/callback by myself? javascript

Tags: javascript, titanium

I would like to call a function after two http call finished.

So I need to wait until two http call finished.

This code is titanium however, structure is common for javascript-like langs.

I made some code for now,,, however I am not sure how to handle original callback....

```
var flg1 = false;
var flg2 = false;

function(callback if (flg1 && flg2)){console.log"Now two flg is changedd!!!";}


// first http call
var pram={};
var url = "http://myapiserver.com/api/test";
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload : function(e) {
        Ti.API.info("first call is success!!");   
    　  flg1 = true; //change flg to true
    　  });
    },
    timeout : 3000
});

client.open("GET", url);
client.setRequestHeader('Content-type','charset=utf-8');
client.send(pram);


// second http call
var pram2={};
var url2 = "http://myapiserver.com/api/test2";
var client2 = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload : function(e) {
        Ti.API.info("second call is success!!");   
    　  　  flg2 = true; //change flg to true
    　  });
    },
    timeout : 3000
});

client2.open("GET", url);
client2.setRequestHeader('Content-type','charset=utf-8');
client2.send(pram2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Titanium, but I think it supports [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and you should try to use the [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method to execute something when both calls have concluded.

Either way, you can wrap everything in promises yourself, as such:

```
var p1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var pram={};
    var url = "http://myapiserver.com/api/test";
    var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload : function(e) {
            // extract data from e,
            data = e
            resolve(data)
        },
        onerror: function (error) {
            reject(error)
        },
        timeout : 3000
    });

    client.open("GET", url);
    client.setRequestHeader('Content-type','charset=utf-8');
    client.send(pram);
})


// second http call
var p2 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var pram2={};
    var url2 = "http://myapiserver.com/api/test2";
    var client2 = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload : function(e) {
            // extract data from e,
            data = e
            resolve(data)
        },
        onerror: function (error) {
            reject(error)
        },
        timeout : 3000
    });

    client2.open("GET", url);
    client2.setRequestHeader('Content-type','charset=utf-8');
    client2.send(pram2);
}

Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(function (dataComingFromP1, dataComingFromP2) {
     // magik
})
```

If you need to polyfill Promises as they're not supported by Titanium by default (again, I'm not a Titanium user), there are lot of libraries on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=promise) you can use.

Comment: Thank you very much. somehow data from p1 and data from p2 are added into dataComingFromP1.(dataComingFromP2 is undefined). However I think it is another problem. thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I've corrected the example. There was no call to `resolve` in the second Promise. Anyway, look into the manual to understand how promises work!